# How to reference sections in rmarkdown with pdf output

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

How do I use `\label` and `\ref` to link sections in `rmarkdown` when outputting to pdf please. I have tried various permutations from https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html and https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html with no success.

One attempt

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---
See Section \@ref(sec:label).

# Section One  (\#sec:label)
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your document as follows:

```
---
title: "Untitled 1"
date: "28 de junio de 2020"
link-citations: yes
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc_depth: 2
---

\section{This is the first section} \label{section1}

You will be some in \ref{section1}
```

[image]

Then you can see how numbers appear, just add `\label{}` to your sections and use `\ref{}` to call. Also, I suggest using `\section{}`, and modify `YAML` as I included. Hoping this can help.

Comment: Great thanks. So it seems it is the option `number_sections: yes` that works the magic of allowing standard latex referencing to work